# Cannot create Object of function defined in closure?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that I can't create an object from a function defined in a closure?

```
var outer = function() {
  var constructor = function() { 
    this.foo = 1; 
  }; 
  return constructor;
};

// Should be: { foo: 1 }, but is: undefined
var constructorObject = new outer()();

// This works
var c = outer();
var constructorObject = new c();
```

Comment: The `inner` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: function doesn't return anything and sets foo on the context object... try this: `var ctxt = {}; new outer().call(ctxt); console.log(ctxt.foo);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the outer function call in parenthesis like so:

```
var constructorObject = new (outer())();
//                          ^       ^ parenthesis here

console.log(constructorObject); // constructor {foo: 1} 
console.log(constructorObject.foo); // 1
```

Comment: Ah I get it!
The new is applied to 'outer' instead of the return of 'outer' (which is 'constructor'). Tricky :)

Answer (score 3):

Because by calling `()()` you get the `inner` function result. And as `inner` function doesn't have `return` statement it equals to `undefined.`

If you want to return object there your function should be like:

```
var inner = function() {
    return { foo: 1 };
}
```

Comment: I think the example is a bit misleading. I don't just want to nest functions, I want to return a constructor.

Comment: Further, if you want to create another new object, then break them up into separate lines:  var outerObj = new outer();
var inner = new outerObj();

console.log(inner);

Comment: @tonekk so what do you expect to have in return? `Object` or `constructor`? Or what?

Comment: you can try to return `return this;` then `constructorObject.foo` will equal `1`. This is what you want?